# Scala - Cannot resolve symbol flatMap

Tags: scala, flatmap

```
def pinShare(id: String, teamOpt: Option[String], expireTime: Long, interestOpt: Option[List[Interest]]): Future[Unit] = {
    for {
      teamObj     <- teamOpt.map(team => teamRepository.getTeam(team)).getOrElse(Future.successful(None))
      interestObj <- interestOpt.getOrElse(TR) // **says cannot resolve symbol flatmap here.**
      share       <- shareRepository.findOneById(id).getOrFailWith(ShareNotFoundException)
      _           <- shareRepository.pinShare(share.id, teamObj, expireTime, interestObj)
    } yield {
      Future(postUpdateActions(id, None))

      ()
    }
```

Says "Cannot resolve symbol flatMap" on the line of interestObj. How can I solve this?

Comment: How `TR` is defined?

Comment: It's a Value(String). Value("tr")

Comment: It would help if you can provide a minimal version of all the functions in your code, only the type signature is enough, their implementations can always be `???`

Answer (score 1):

Change this line Form

```
interestObj <- interestOpt.getOrElse(TR)
```

To

```
interestObj = interestOpt.getOrElse(TR)
```

Comment: That will seriously change semantics. Also I doubt it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that `interestOpt.getOrElse(TR)` doesn't have `List` type.

Declare `TR` to have `List[Interest]` type.

Comment: That still won't work because the code has many other errors due to the mix of multiple monads in a single `for`

Comment: I can't provide fix for problems I don't see :(

Comment: Yeah totally agree, that is why I asked OP for clarification because I also don't understand what is the intended beavoiur. Especially that `Future` inside the `yield` really confuses me.